# How to Create an Indefinite Number of Charts with Loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, charts

I have data from an indefinite number of years in a spreadsheet. The data I have is laid out as it is in the imgur screenshot. Currently, I have 3 years of data (2016-2018), but I want my code to be able to work for an indefinite number of years since I'll be using it for datasets with any number of years of data. I want to make this data into three graphs per year: Average Disease Risk ####, Average Disease Cost ####, Average Biometrics ####. I'd like these graphs to be displayed on the same spread sheet as the data lined up in three columns and ascending in years.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJjsH.jpg

The code below is just for Average Disease Risk #### graphs.

```
Sub ChartMake()

Dim ChartCount As Integer
ChartCount = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count

If ChartCount > 0 Then
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
End If

Dim NLoops As Integer, LoopNumber As Integer

NLoops = Worksheets("Data Input").Range("Q2").Value - 1

LoopNumber = 1

Dim cht As ChartObject, rngChart As Range, destinationSheet As String, Results As Worksheet, StartRow As Integer, EndRow As Integer, StartChart As Integer, EndChart As Integer

Set Results = Worksheets("Results")

destinationSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

Do While NLoops >= 0

StartRow = NLoops * 27
EndRow = NLoops * 27 + 5
StartChart = NLoops * 9 + 9
EndChart = NLoops * 9 + 17

Set co = Sheets("Results").ChartObjects.Add(6, StartChart, 5, 8)
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Results.Range(Results.Cells(StartRow, "A"), Results.Cells(EndRow, "B"))
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(72, 72, 72)
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Color = RGB(72, 72, 72)
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Color = RGB(72, 72, 72)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(LoopNumber).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(59, 110, 172)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(LoopNumber).Points(2).Interior.Color = RGB(59, 110, 172)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(LoopNumber).Points(3).Interior.Color = RGB(59, 110, 172)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(LoopNumber).Points(4).Interior.Color = RGB(59, 110, 172)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(LoopNumber).Format.Shadow.Visible = msoTrue
Set cht = ActiveChart.Parent
With cht
.Left = Results.Cells(StartChart, "F").Left
.Top = Results.Cells(StartChart, "F").Top
.Height = Results.Range(Results.Cells(StartChart, "F"), Cells(EndChart, "J")).Height
.Width = Results.Range(Results.Cells(StartChart, "F"), Cells(EndChart, "J")).Width
End With
ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Delete

NLoops = NLoops - 1

LoopNumber = LoopNumber + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

When the code loops, it reassigns the source data to the year of the next loop and gets moved to the spot for the next year too (the 2018 graph becomes the 2017 graph effectively). I assume this is related to how I made the chart or chart object or using ActiveChart.

How can I make a new chart each time instead? I don't know how to make a new chart object for each loop indefinitely.

Comment: Use `co.Chart` instead of `ActiveChart`

Comment: That yields a new error here:

co.Chart.SeriesCollection(LoopNumber).Points(1).Interior.Color = RGB(59, 110, 172)

Run-time error '1004': Parameter not valid.

Switching that section of the code to ActiveChart didn't fix the problem either.

This occurs on the second time through the loop.

This did create a second graph, which is great! Thank you.

Comment: I'm not really following what's going on with those loop counters, but you're adding to `LoopNumber` with each new chart, so eventually that value will exceed the number of series on your chart.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem! It functions completely now!

Comment: Good to hear you got it fixed.